# SQLCMD -L Returns Bizarre Response Instead of Server List

Tags: sql-server-2014, sqlcmd

I have a server with three installed SQL Server 2014 instances with Service Pack 1 (build number is 12.0.4213.0) installed. When I run SQLCMD -L on the server I am getting the bizarre response below.

> C:\Users\Tester>sqlcmd -L
>
> Servers:
>       ;UID:Login ID=?;PWD:Password=?;Trusted_Connection:Use Integrated Security=?;
>   *APP:AppName=?;*WSID:WorkStation ID=?;

The SQL Server is running normally and the SQL Browser service is started. Querying the SQL Browser service with another tool on the same server yields the expected results. I can run regular SQL queries with SQLCMD and get the expected results.

I was able to verify that the output above is the same on a workstation where I caused SQLCMD -L to receive no responses at all by enabling the firewall; however, the firewall is not an issue on this server. I've checked the settings and, as stated previously, my other tool gets SQL Browser Service responses to a broadcast just fine.

Also, running WHERE reports that the path to SQLCMD is `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE`, which is correct per [File Locations for Default and Named Instances of SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143547(v=sql.120).aspx).

Does anyone have any idea why SQLCMD is doing this and how to fix it?

Comment: I checked the path and even executed the command with the full path specified. Also, this server has never had any SQL version other than 2014 on it.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen with a computer, probably a laptop, that is not joined to the domain.